# Solving differential equation related to Kummer's equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I am trying to find a solution $u_l(r)$ to the following differential equation:

$\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+k^2-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}-\frac{2\eta k}{r}\right)u_l(r) = 0$

I am being told to make the Ansatz $u_l(r) = e^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}f_l(x)$, where $x=-2ikr$, and then show that $f_l(x)$ fulfills Kummer's equation:

$\left(x\frac{d^2}{dx^2}+(2l+2-x)\frac{d}{dx}-(l+1+i\eta)\right)f_l(x)=0$

I am unsure why the part with Kummer's equation is related to the original problem, unless there is some way to rewrite the differential equation $\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+k^2-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}-\frac{2\eta k}{r}\right)u_l(r) = 0$ so it is similar to Kummer's equation. Is there a formal way to do this using $x=-2ikr$?

Comment: Can you give us some context?  I remember doing these kinds of transformations when I sat down to fully solve the Shcrodinger equation for two bosons in a harmonic trap interacting via a contact interaction. Are you doing something similar?  In that case, the solutions to Kummer's equation end up being convenient for matching solutions "at" the delta-function (i.e., satisfying a Bethe-Peirels boundary condition) by using the asymptotic forms of these functions.

Comment: Also, I'm unclear as to what your question is. Are you asking what steps are required to get from the first differential equation to the second, or why one would do that in the first place?

Comment: sorry, I realise I might have been a bit unclear, but I guess that comes from me being a bit confused about what i'm being asked in the exercise I'm doing. This is a problem from physics, I am working with quantum mechanical scattering on the Coulomb potential. The way the problem is posed it seems I should be able to show just from the ansatz that the part $f_l(x)$ solves the Kummer equation, thus showing that $f_l(x)$ is a generalized hypergeomtric series. I can link the problem if that helps!

Comment: https://imgur.com/grTsDZu Here's a link to a picture of the problem

Comment: The idea is to just plug in the ansatz to the original differential equation and manipulate until you have a differential equation for $f_l(r)$. I would say it's easier to do in steps. First plug in the ansatz with $g(r)$ in place of $f_l(x)$, then change variables to $x=-2ikr$.  I'll write an answer with some of the steps.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with
$$
\left(\frac{d^2}{dr^2}+k^2-\frac{l(l+1)}{r^2}-\frac{2\eta k}{r}\right)u_l(r) = 0,
$$
we assume that the function $u_l(r)$ has the form
$$
u_l(r) = e^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g(r).
$$
Plug this directly into the equation above to derive a differential equation for $g(r)$. Here are some of the steps.

- The second derivative term yields many terms. Using the product rule, one derivative yields three term:
  $$
  \frac{du_l}{dr} = ike^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g(r) + e^{ikr}k(l+1)(kr)^{l}g(r) +e^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g'(r)\,.
  $$
  Then, applying the derivative again yields nine terms:
  \begin{align}
  \frac{d^2u_l}{dr^2} &=(ik)^2e^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g(r) + ike^{ikr}k(l+1)(kr)^{l}g(r) + ike^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g'(r)\\
  &\mbox{}\quad+
  ike^{ikr}k(l+1)(kr)^{l}g(r) + e^{ikr}k^2l(l+1)(kr)^{l-1}g(r) +e^{ikr}k(l+1)(kr)^{l}g'(r)\\
  &\mbox{}\quad+
  ike^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g'(r) + e^{ikr}k(l+1)(kr)^{l}g'(r)+e^{ikr}(kr)^{l+1}g''(r)\,.
  \end{align}
- The other terms are all multiplication by some function, so we get only one term each from them.
- Multiply through by $r^2$.
- We can then combine terms (in $g$, $g''$, and $g'$) and factor out (and cancel) an $e^{ikr}$ and some power of $(kr)$ from each term, leaving
  $$
  0=2ik(1+l+i\eta)g(r)+2(l+1+ikr)g'(r)+rg''(r).
  $$

Then, we can make the final change of variables, by
$$
f_l(x) = g\left(\frac{-ix}{2k}\right), 
$$
effected by plugging in $-ix/2k$ for $r$ everywhere. In the derivative terms, we just note (schematically) that
$$
\frac{d}{dr} = \frac{d}{d(-ix/2k)}=-\frac{2k}{i}\frac{d}{dx},
$$
and
$$
\frac{d^2}{dr^2} = \left(-\frac{2k}{i}\right)^2\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\,.
$$
Putting these pieces together will yield, at the end of the day,
$$
0=xf_l''(x)+(2+2l-x)f_l'(x)-(1+l+i\eta)f_l(x).
$$

Comment: Thank you so much, this is great help!

Comment: @zucian There's a possibility that I've made some small algebraic errors, especially in all the derivatives, but it should show you the general idea.